# 2x3 mixed linear model

Tags: anova

I have a 2x3 mixed ANOVA design.  There are three treatments, with each being tested before and after treatment.  I want to test whether there is a significant difference in treatment, but the results I ma seeing don't make sense.  I have an overall effect of treatment X session, but I'm confused on how to see if treatment 1 differs from treatment 2 and 3, accounting for the fact that they have different baselines.   I will be using JMP to analyze the data.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: So, I can clearly see that treatment 1(control) has no effect, whereas treatment 2 and 3 have an effect using the interaction term.  Now I want to be able to say that treatment 2 and 3 are significantly different from treatment 1 (control).  This is different from looking at an overall treatment effect since the baselines are not equivalent between all groups.  Please help.

Comment: FYI, these are not the same subjects in the three treatment groups.